# Escrever arquivo de imagem com nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Recebo uma imagem no formato image:data e preciso salva-lá como imagem no servidor, tentei:

```
  var imageData = req.body.imagem.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

  fs.writeFile(url, imageData, 'base64', function(err) {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    new UsuarioModel().updateFoto(req.body.id, url).then(function (rows) {
      res.json(rows);
    }, function (err) {
      res.send(err);
    })
  });
```

Isso não ocasiona nenhum erro, gera o arquivo com o nome correto, no entanto as imagens ficam em branco, já verifiquei se os diretórios tinham permissão e se a **image:data** estava correta e tudo está certo. Alguém saberia como posso solucionar este problema ?

Comment: O express não gere bem receber ficheiros. Precisas de um plugin, o multer é um dos que é mais usado segundo sei: https://github.com/expressjs/multer